# What are the changes done in OWA_UTIL.who_called_me as part of 18C upgrade?

Tags: oracle, plsql, updates

```
OWA_UTIL.WHO_CALLED_ME(
   owner          OUT      VARCHAR2,
   name           OUT      VARCHAR2,
   lineno         OUT      NUMBER,
   caller_t       OUT      VARCHAR2);
```

This procedure returns information (in the form of output parameters) about the PL/SQL code unit that invoked it.Is there any change that has happened as part of Oracle 18C upgrade. I heard that name variable will now have package name along with the procedure name, earlier it was just proc/function name

Answer (score 2):

In 11g `OWA_UTIL.WHO_CALLED_ME` returned the fact that the caller was a package, but did not include the name of the procedure within the package. You had to determine the calling procedure by using the line number returned by `WHO_CALLED_ME` and examining the source code of the package body. [11g dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=925e88fc73da8b961f0fa63556928898)

In 18c the `NAME` returned by `WHO_CALLED_ME` includes both the package name and the procedure name within the package. The line number is still returned. [18c dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=972a3a1c78a0e1347374c811f065cce0)